# How to get all details using filter condition in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

**This is my scenario**

I have user data in the user database.

```
Example
{
    id:1,
   email:'her@gmail.com'

}
```

**filter condition**

```
sample = user.objects.filter(email='her@gmail.com')
print(sample.id)
```

I tried to print user id.but its throwing error.how to print id in the filter condition? and why its throw error any issue?.

Comment: show us the error

Comment: Your query will return a queryset objects **(iterable objects)**. And you can simply `sample[0].id` to access it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`filter`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#filter) returns a new **QuerySet** objects.

If you want to retrieve a single object, you maybe do this:

`user.objects.get(email='her@gmail.com')`